# How program arithmetics on general objects which become defined only later?

Tags: java, generics

I want to program arithmetics for objects which can be different in nature and are defined afterwards (real number, complex numbers, matrices,...). Once arithmetics is implemented, I can still add new types. A common feature is that they are all characterized by a set of real numbers (double[]), but the implementation for addition, multiplication etc. is different.

I have tied to define an `interface`:

```
interface GeneralNumber
{
    void set(double[] z)
    double element(int i);
    GeneralNumber addition(GeneralNumber a, GeneralNumber b);
}
```

Then:

```
public class ComplexNumber implements GeneralNumber
{
    double[] k;

    @Override
    public void set(double[] z)
    {
        k[0]=z[0];
        k[1]=z[1];
    }

    @Override
    public double element(int i)
    {
        return k[i];
    }

    @Override
    GeneralNumber addition(GeneralNumber a, GeneralNumber b)
    {
        double aR = a.element(0);
        double aI = a.element(1);

        double bR = b.element(0);
        double bI = b.element(1);

        double[] c = {aR+bR,aI+bI};

        GeneralNumber result = new ComplexNumber();
        result.set(c);

        return result;
    }
```

In a *third* class, when I program some algebraic operations on `GeneralNumber`, I run into problems. Imagine that in the third class I call the method `computeSomething` with `ComplexNumber` objects (so the tpye information *is* there) and *try* to do something like this (which does not work)

```
GeneralNumber computeSomething(GeneralNumber a, GeneralNumber b)
{
    GeneralNumber c = GeneralNumber.addition(a,b)
    ....
}
```

I would like Java to recognize inputs as `ComplexNumber` and use the `addition` method from `ComplexNumber` as if it was a static method.

Needles to say that I am unable to create new `GeneralNumber` instances, because Java does not know which one (I can only try to clone existing `GeneralNumbers` and then work with them..). There should be some elegant way....  For example I may want to do something like

```
GeneralNumber unity = new GeneralNumber.generateFromDouble(1.0);
```

Because 1.0 (or generally, a real number) may be very often easily generalized to more general unity object (identity matrix, matrix with the number on the diagonal, etc...). Clearly the "type" of "GeneralNumber" should appear somewhere... but where, for the whole approach to be elegant? To be a good practice?

I tried to use an abstract class, but things are not better, I still run into  basically the same problems. When trying to work with `GeneralNumber` in `computeSomething` I cannot use `static`:

```
GeneralNumber.addition(a,b)
```

In `GeneralNumber` it is not implemented, and in `ComplexNumber` it cannot be  `static`.

Maybe Java generics help here... I was speculating without finding solution.

The question is obvious:

How to program arithmetics which is valid for different objects, each object(type) implementing its own version of the operation (eg. addition, multiplication) in a way which looks like `static`?

Comment: In addition(a,b), do a and b have to be of the exact same subtype?

Comment: Yes. The whole computation is meant to be done with the same subtype.

Comment: All Java numbers are already children of `Number` parent class. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html

Comment: @m0skit0 That only scratches the surface, and is not suitable for modeling arithmetics as described here. Broadly speaking, arithmetics are the application of algebraic operations, and one can go very far with sorting this out. For example, the http://jscience.org/api/org/jscience/mathematics/structure/package-summary.html package made some steps in this direction. The requirements probably have to be a bit clearer in order to give a "good" answer, but maybe I'll give it a try...

Comment: m0skit0: you may notice that the "Number" class does not have arithmetic operations as methods... and this I wan to have.

Comment: take a look at m0skit0's link: http://jscience.org/api/org/jscience/mathematics/structure/package-summary.html. see field especially: http://jscience.org/api/org/jscience/mathematics/structure/Field.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic arithmetic operations are addition, subtraction, multiplication and division. And these are essentially [Algebraic Operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_operation). This means that they are operations on an algebraic structure, and the structure is essentially what you tried to model with your interface. Specifically, the structure that you need for these operations is a [Field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)).

There already are libraries that [model a `Field` class](http://jscience.org/api/org/jscience/mathematics/structure/Field.html) and give a glimpse at how complicated this can be if you're trying to do it **right**. In the purest sense, there is no such thing as "subtraction", but only the addition of the [inverse element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_element). Similarly, a division is the multiplication with the [multiplicative inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_inverse), with 0.0 being the odd case where no such element exists. Ouch.

The exact semantics of methods like `double element_i(int i);` would have to be specified. Sure, it makes sense for complex numbers, but not for all possible implementations.

A **very** simplistic sketch of a possible `GeneralNumber` interface and one implementation is shown here:

```
class Arithmetic
{
    static <T> GeneralNumber<T> computeSomething(
        GeneralNumber<T> a, GeneralNumber<T> b)
    {
        GeneralNumber<T> c = a.add(b);             // c      = a + b
        GeneralNumber<T> d = c.additiveInverse();  // d      = -c
        GeneralNumber<T> result = c.multiply(d);   // result = c * d
        return result;
    }
}

interface GeneralNumber<T>
{
    T get();

    GeneralNumber<T> add(GeneralNumber<T> a);
    GeneralNumber<T> additiveInverse();
    GeneralNumber<T> additiveNeutral();

    GeneralNumber<T> multiply(GeneralNumber<T> a);
    GeneralNumber<T> multiplicativeInverse();
    GeneralNumber<T> multiplicativeNeutral();
}

class GeneralDoubleNumber implements GeneralNumber<Double>
{
    static GeneralDoubleNumber of(double d)
    {
        return new GeneralDoubleNumber(d);
    }

    private final double value;
    public GeneralDoubleNumber(double d)
    {
        this.value = d;
    }

    @Override
    public Double get()
    {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public GeneralNumber<Double> add(GeneralNumber<Double> a)
    {
        return of(get() + a.get());
    }

    @Override
    public GeneralNumber<Double> additiveInverse()
    {
        return of(-get());
    }

    @Override
    public GeneralNumber<Double> additiveNeutral()
    {
        return of(0.0);
    }

    @Override
    public GeneralNumber<Double> multiply(GeneralNumber<Double> a)
    {
        return of(get() * a.get());
    }

    @Override
    public GeneralNumber<Double> multiplicativeInverse()
    {
        return of(1.0 / get());
    }

    @Override
    public GeneralNumber<Double> multiplicativeNeutral()
    {
        return of(1.0);
    }

}
```

But note that, in some ways, it would make sense to pull the operations out of the structures that they operate on. And keep in mind that the complexity of all this tends to grow out of hand when you consider the fact that the arithmetic operations may modify the **domain**. The difference between an `Instant` and an `Instant` should not be an `Instant`, but a `Duration`...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
interface generalNumber {
    void set(double[] z);
    double element_i(int i);
    generalNumber addition(generalNumber a);
    static generalNumber addition(generalNumber a,generalNumber b) {
        return a.addition(b);
    }
}
class complexNumber implements generalNumber {
    double[] k;
    @Override public void set(double[] z) {
        k=new double[2];
        k[0]=z[0];
        k[1]=z[1];
    }
    @Override public double element_i(int i) {
        return k[i];
    }
    @Override public generalNumber addition(generalNumber a) {
        if(!(a instanceof complexNumber)) throw new RuntimeException(a+" is not a "+getClass().getName());
        double aR=this.element_i(0);
        double aI=this.element_i(1);
        double bR=a.element_i(0);
        double bI=a.element_i(1);
        double[] c= {aR+bR,aI+bI};
        generalNumber result=new complexNumber();
        result.set(c);
        return result;
    }
    @Override public String toString() {
        return "complexNumber [k="+Arrays.toString(k)+"]";
    }
}
class copyOfComplexNumber implements generalNumber {
    double[] k;
    @Override public void set(double[] z) {
        k=new double[2];
        k[0]=z[0];
        k[1]=z[1];
    }
    @Override public double element_i(int i) {
        return k[i];
    }
    @Override public generalNumber addition(generalNumber a) {
        if(!(a instanceof copyOfComplexNumber)) throw new RuntimeException(a+" is not a "+getClass().getName());
        double aR=this.element_i(0);
        double aI=this.element_i(1);
        double bR=a.element_i(0);
        double bI=a.element_i(1);
        double[] c= {aR+bR,aI+bI};
        generalNumber result=new complexNumber();
        result.set(c);
        return result;
    }
    @Override public String toString() {
        return "copyOfComplexNumber [k="+Arrays.toString(k)+"]";
    }
}
public class So53765596_how_program_arithmetics_on_general_objects_which_become_defined_only_later {
    generalNumber computeSomething(generalNumber a,generalNumber b) {
        return generalNumber.addition(a,b);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] a_=new double[] {1,2};
        double[] b_=new double[] {3,4};
        generalNumber a=new complexNumber();
        a.set(a_);
        generalNumber b=new complexNumber();
        b.set(b_);
        System.out.println(a+"+"+b+"="+generalNumber.addition(a,b));
        a=new copyOfComplexNumber();
        a.set(a_);
        b=new copyOfComplexNumber();
        b.set(b_);
        System.out.println(a+"+"+b+"="+generalNumber.addition(a,b));
    }
}
```

Comment: I am puzzled. What is a difference between "complexNumber" and "copyOfComplexNumber"? They look exactly the same (except name). Is there some purpose?

Comment: They are the same, but they could be different. I was too lazy to think of something for real.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are only adding numbers of the same type, it is safe to implement 
`generalNumber addition(generalNumber b);`
Inside it would use `this` as `a` from your original function

And the usage would look like:

```
generalNumber computeSomething(generalNumber a, generalNumber b)
    {
       generalNumber c = a.addition(b); // now c is a + b
       .... 
       return c;
    }
```